# Pass arguments by value in C: how big is too big?

Tags: c

I'd be interested to know what seasoned C programmers think is an upper bound for the size of an argument which can be passed by value.

Context: I have occasion to work with 2×2 matrices, which I have in a struct:

```c
typedef struct
{
  double a, b, c, d;
} mat_t;
```

Now it makes life a *lot* easier if I can pass by value, particularly for composite operations

```c
mat_t A = mat_sum(mat_smul(lambda, B), C);
```

for *A = λB + C*, for example.  At the same time I'm aware that pass-by-value involves copying things to the runtime stack so comes with a cost if those things are big.

That the C language standard library passes complex numbers by value suggests "two doubles" as a reasonable lower bound, but a reasonable upper bound?

Comment: Can be or should be? Can be: There is no general limit for how much can be passed; it depends on the implementation and various circumstances. Should be: That involves a variety of circumstances, goals, values, and opinion, and is too broad a question, and likely no specific answer is possible.

Comment: How long is a string? I have a hard time seeing a good rule of thumb here. It's entirely depends on what you're doing.

Comment: I'd say that it's small enough until it turns out to be one of your top three bottlenecks when you measure and profile.

Comment: One view is this is not particularly a question about function arguments. It is a subset of this question: If we need to make a copy of X, should we define an automatic local variable for the copy or use `malloc`? Maybe an answer is if making a local copy is not going to jeopardize your stack limit, do that.

Comment: Implement both and benchmark.

Comment: Of course it _can_ be as big as you like (or as big as your stack), I'm asking for what seasoned C programmers would regard as best practice.  My gut says "four doubles" is fine, but for 3×3 matrices I would think that was too big, I'd pass by reference.  Hence I'm interested in the views of others.

Comment: If you are motivated by simplicity, you might consider switching to C++ where you can write: `auto A = lambda * B + C;` and let the matrix object implementor make the best choices regarding pass by value and pass by const reference. Of course the rest of C++ is not simple :)

Comment: The question is, why WOULD you want to pass by value big data blocks? There is no benefit at all, and just slows your application down.

Comment: On AMD64, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/FeepingCreature/5dff669aad380a123b15659e195fb96c) suggests a maximum of 16 bytes; see also [this discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=38875422) on Hacker News.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, passing the matrices by value does not cause much overhead compared to passing them by reference (ie: passing a pointer to local matrix objects) and is much more readable as you mention.

What seems important for code generation is the ability to inline these functions. Modern compilers are quite good at this, but it can help to define the functions as `static inline` in the header file.

Look at the [code generated](https://godbolt.org/z/4hdoWjKsj) for this simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    double a, b, c, d;
} mat_t;

mat_t mat_sum(mat_t m1, mat_t m2) {
    return (mat_t){ m1.a + m2.a, m1.b + m2.b, m1.c + m2.c, m1.d + m2.d };
}

mat_t mat_smul(double x, mat_t m) {
    return (mat_t){ x * m.a, x * m.b, x * m.c, x * m.d };
}

mat_t *mat_sump(mat_t *res, const mat_t *m1, const mat_t *m2) {
    res->a = m1->a + m2->a;
    res->b = m1->b + m2->b;
    res->c = m1->c + m2->c;
    res->d = m1->d + m2->d;
    return res;
}

mat_t *mat_smulp(mat_t *res, double x, const mat_t *m) {
    res->a = x * m->a;
    res->b = x * m->b;
    res->c = x * m->c;
    res->d = x * m->d;
    return res;
}

void mat_print(const char *name, mat_t M) {
    printf("%s: { %g, %g, %g, %g };\n", name, M.a, M.b, M.c, M.d);
}

mat_t A = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
mat_t B = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
double lambda = 2.5;

int main() {
    mat_t C = mat_sum(mat_smul(lambda, A), B);
    mat_print("C", C);

    mat_t T;
    mat_sump(&C, mat_smulp(&T, lambda, &A), &B);
    mat_print("C", C);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- but sadly, ASM has always been a mystery to me so I'm not sure what I'm looking at, is the by-value or by-reference version easier to inline?

Comment: The assembly on godbolt shows that both approaches are suboptimal when used as functions, but produce the same more efficient code when inlined in the `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

An upper bound is basically the stack size. On Windows it's usually 1MB and on Linux 8MB. This can be changed with compiler flags. In practice, I'd say the upper bound is MUCH lower, but I don't have a good rule of thumb for that.

The only rule of thumb that's relevant here is that you should use pointers for structs in general.

Large structures can give a huge performance hit because of unnecessary copying.

And I cannot really see how it would make things so much easier. Because you can easily do something like this:

```
T foo(mat_t *A) {
    mat_t a = *A;

    // Continue as if A was not a pointer but use a instead
```

If you really feel that you need to copy the whole struct just to make the rest a little bit easier, use the above method, because that will make it A LOT easier when you realize that you need to refactor the code because it's too slow.

Comment: Why the memcpy when you could simply do `a = *A;`?

Comment: @user694733 Thanks, you're completely right

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly subjective, but in general it goes like this:

Everyone generally agrees that "primitive data types" (integers, floating point, pointers etc) are fine to pass by value. Within reason, if you have more than 5 or so parameters then perhaps you should have used a struct instead.

Some programmers think structs are fine to pass by value if they only contain a few of such primitive data types. Or at least as long as you keep the struct size below the data word size of the CPU. Others are more strict and say that structs should always be passed by reference no matter how big or small, because that makes your coding style consistent, but also because there's not much in the way of performance difference when accessing parameters indirectly through a pointer compared to accessing local variables directly. Copying data to the stack is always a performance hit though, in case the function couldn't be inlined.

There's no obvious right or wrong though, since this boils down to system calling convention and stack frame format.

Everyone generally agrees that you shouldn't allocate huge arrays or structs on the stack, due to the potential for stack overflow. "Huge" might mean 100 bytes or it might mean thousands of bytes, again depending on system.

If looking at the most low-end systems with just a few general-purpose registers and very limited stack, then in some cases you have to bake all parameters into a struct and pass that one by reference, in order to speed up the function call and reduce stack use.